# Route not active on Travel modes in directions as default

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I use the [Travel Modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes) option of the Google Maps Directions Service on my website.

As default (before the user selects `Mode of Travel`), the route does not show and users have to select any Mode of Travel before they see the route on map.

I've changed

```
var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
```

to

```
var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value= 'DRIVING';
```

But it does not work.

Does anyone know how I can show the route *before* the user selects a `mode`?

Answer (score 0):

The function `calcRoute` will be executed when the `change`-event of the dropdown fires.

To run the function initially without a user-action simply call `calcRoute();` at the end of `initialize()`